# Getting the three next days

Tags: javascript, beginner, datetime, ecmascript-6

I'm simply getting the 3 future days from an array of objects based on the current day to display for a weather component.

This is the first time I've attempted using ES6 and it's features so please take this into consideration.

Is there a better way to do this and save the values? Have I overcomplicated the whole thing?

```
const days = [
  {0: 'Sun'},
  {1: 'Mon'},
  {2: 'Tue'},
  {3: 'Wed'},
  {4: 'Thu'},
  {5: 'Fri'},
  {6: 'Sat'}
];
let currentDay = new Date(Date.now()).getDay();
const offset = currentDay + 1;
const daysLength = days.length;
let counter = 0;
let newDays = [];

for (const [i, day] of days.entries()) {
  // set the index start point.
  let pointer = (i + offset) % daysLength;
  newDays.push(days[pointer][pointer]);
  counter++
  if (counter === 3) { break; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have overcomplicated things. But it's nothing dramatic.

First, you defined a two-dimensional table for getting the name of a day. You can replace this with a one-dimensional array.

```
const dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
```

With this definition, you can just say `dayNames[pointer]` instead of your current `dayNames[pointer][pointer]`.

The `for` loop should be of the form `for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { }`, which is the idiomatic form of saying *three times*.

```
const today = (new Date()).getDay();
const nextDays = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  nextDays.push(dayNames[(today + 1 + i) % dayNames.length]);
}
```

This counts `i` from 0 to 2. At first it may feel a bit easier to let `i` count from 1 to 3 instead, making the `+ 1` unnecessary. Amongst experienced programmers, almost all loops start at 0 though, so whenever you start a loop at a nonzero number, you will confuse them a little bit.